# I want to know how to add a URL to a ics

Tags: r, url, calendar, icalendar

I simply want to add a URL to an ics within R to automate some e-mails to allow people to add zoom meetings to their calendars ...

So far all seems fine except I am not clear how to add the URL ...

```
flo.hen = ic_event(start_time="2020-08-25 12:00",
      end_time=.5,
      summary = "TEST THIS",more_properties=TRUE,
      event_properties="URL:https://us.zoom.us/j/8055551212")

write_ics(flo.hen,"/users/srein/Desktop/test.ics")
```

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

S

Answer (score 1):

Try it like this:

```
flo.hen = ic_event(start_time="2020-08-25 12:00",
                   end_time=.5,
                   summary = "TEST THIS",more_properties=TRUE,
                   event_properties=c("URL" = "https://us.zoom.us/j/8055551212"))
```

Event properties are specified as a named vector. i.e:

```
event_properties=c("URL" = "https://my.url", "EMAIL" = "my@email.com")
```

You can find all the options by checking the "properties" object that comes with the package:

```
properties

[1] "CALSCALE"     "METHOD"       "PRODID"       "VERSION"      "ATTACH"       "CATEGORIES"   "CLASS"        "COMMENT"     
 [9] "DESCRIPTION"  "GEO"          "LOCATION"     "PERCENT"      "PRIORITY"     "RESOURCES"    "STATUS"       "SUMMARY"     
[17] "COMPLETED"    "DTEND"        "DUE"          "DTSTART"      "DURATION"     "FREEBUSY"     "TRANSP"       "TZID"        
[25] "TZNAME"       "TZOFFSETFROM" "TZOFFSETTO"   "TZURL"        "ATTENDEE"     "CONTACT"      "ORGANIZER"    "RECURRENCE"  
[33] "RELATED"      "URL"          "UID"          "EXDATE"       "RDATE"        "RRULE"        "ACTION"       "REPEAT"      
[41] "TRIGGER"      "CREATED"      "DTSTAMP"      "LAST"         "SEQUENCE"     "REQUEST"      "FLOAT"        "INTEGER"     
[49] "AUDIO"        "DISPLAY"      "EMAIL"        "PUBLIC"       "PRIVATE"      "CONFIDENTIAL"
```

Comment: @SteveRein no prob! You can mark this answers as "accepted" so others will know it solved your problem when they arrive here with the same issue (see https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers )